# Parse string to Date in JavaScript with any format but specific locale for ambiguous cases

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, luxon, dayjs

Is there a JavaScript library that can parse strings to datetime as in e.g. C#? What I mean is a way such that I don't have to specify each date format that could occur (e.g. 1/19/2021, 2021-1-1, 1-Jan-21), but I can specify locale so that in ambiguous cases where multiple options are available right option would be chosen?
E.g. in C# I can do something like this:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Pare(myDateString, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This will know that 1/2/2021 is February 1st (and not January 2nd), but it will also properly parse 1/19/2021 (it will not throw exception because 19th month doesn't exist) and everything else.

Comment: What you want to do is a bad idea as the "locale" is specified as a language code and that does not reliably indicate the format a user might use. Far better to either specify the format the user must use, or allow them to specify the format.

Comment: I wish if I could say that to a customer. But customers are getting their files from different people from all around the world, there are hundreds of thousands lines of data inside of these files and they are expecting from us to build them system that will work correctly. Idea is that if there are lines that could be e.g. either MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY but there are some lines that could be just one of these formats, then that format should be used in cases when there are multiple options. I know how to do it in a harder way, but I wanted first to check if there is a library that do it.

Comment: Seems you need to associate a format with each customer and use it when parsing their files. If they are mixing formats in the same file, then they have to fix that. You can't be expected to guess what their customers might mean by 03/04/20, that's simply unreasonable, no one can do that reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this from Luxon library:

`public static fromFormat(text: string, fmt: string, opts: Object): DateTime`.

`Create a DateTime from an input string and format string. Defaults to en-US if no locale has been specified, regardless of the system's locale.`

See docs here: [https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html)

Comment: But as you see, it requires date format to be passed in and I don't want to do it because there could be multiple ones and it is annoying to check for each separately.